# How can I do to get correct output in class?

Tags: c++

This is the default constructor with no parameters. By default, this allocates space    for a
double array of size 10 and assigns a default value of 0 to each of them.

its a ""class"" , I m not sure what i m doing right or wrong..

I fill the public body functions , but my output is nothing suppose to print 0000000000
, I m very new to coding.

```
 class DataVector
 {
 private:
     DataType *m_data;//Pointer to dynamically allocated memory that holds all items
     UIntType m_size;//Size of the m_data array

 public:

     DataVector()
     {
         double *m_data = new double[m_size];
         for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
         {
             *m_data = 0;
             m_data++;
         }
     }

     void PrintItems()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
         {
             cout << *m_data << " ";
             m_data++;
         }
     }
};

void TestDataVector()
{
    {
        DataVector d1;
        d1.PrintItems();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this implementation of yours:

- You are not initializing `m_size`
- You change the value of the pointer `m_data` which is supposed to hold the address of first member of the array. So, at the end of the initializer, `m_data` is pointing to a spot one after the block you had allocated by `new`.
- same in the `printItems` member function, but here the pointer already points to an invalid location.
- Also, because you are allocating memory in the constructor, you should also define a destructor to free that memory.